# jquery add class if child class has class xxx

Tags: jquery, addclass

Trying to add a class to a font tag with class "pricecolor" if child has a class of "PageText_L657n".

```
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="64%" valign="top"> Stock Item (Usually Ships Within 24 Hours) <br>
        <font class="text colors_text"><span class="PageText_L483n"><b><span class="PageText_L334n">MSRP</span>: $4,895.00</b> </span></font><br>
        <b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L483n"><font class="text colors_text"><b>Regular Price: </b></font> $1,872.34 </span></font></b><br>
        <br>
      <a class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L657n"><span style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">Click To Get Today's Special Price!</span></a></td>
      <td width="36%" align="right"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(function(){
$(".pricecolor").child().hasClass("PageText_L657n").addClass("ice1");
});

</script>
```

Comment: I certainly hope this isn't code you wrote. I see a `font` tag and non-semantic `table` elements.

Comment: I did not write the code, it is a given template from Volusion stores lol.  I have to find ways to modify it through JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** After clarification, it seems you want this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WeCCT/2/

```
$('.PageText_L657n').closest('td').find('.pricecolor').eq(0).addClass('ice1');
```

This selects elements with the class `PageText_L657n`, then gets its nearest ancestor `<td>` and uses the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to locate nested `.pricecolor` elements, and the [`eq()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to narrow it down to the first before adding the class.

---

**Original answer**

If you want to limit yourself to valid `querySelectorAll` selectors, do this:

```
$('.PageText_L657n').parent('.pricecolor').addClass('ice1');
```

This starts with selecting the `.PageText_L657n` element, then traverses up to its parent and *only* adds the class if the parent has the `.pricecolor` class.

Comment: This does nothing for me as well.  However, if I just have .parent() it will add a class to the parent.  I just want to add the class to the font.pricecolor.

Comment: @ToddN: I'd suggest that it is likely because you have a little invalid markup. You're missing a closing `</span>` tag. The `PageText_L657n` element (or the one inside it) isn't closed.

Comment: ...[here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/WeCCT/) with the fixed tag. Either that or the CSS is defined incorrectly.

Comment: Oh ok I see what your talking about.  Perhaps I worded the question incorrectly.  The strike through should be through the whole "Regular Price: $xx.xx" not the "Click To Get Todays Special Price".

Comment: @ToddN: I see what you're after. I'll update my answer in a second.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$('.pricecolor:has(.PageText_L657n)').addClass('ice1');
```

Comment: This unfortunately does nothing for me.  The class 'ice1' is a strike through so "Regular Price: $1,872.34" should have a strike through it.

Answer (score 0):

The .pageText classes are only in the markup when you are an administrator for that site. Your store will not render your css code on the frontend when you are not logged in because those classes do not exist in the source anymore. I had the same problem since I was always coding while I was logged in to the site.